# Can Retrofit2 onResponse method have Null Response?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using `Retrofit 2.1.0` library, and use `call.enqueue` method to do async API calls.

The `CallBack` class returns `onResponse(Call call, Response response)` and `onFailure (Call call, Throwable t)`.

My question is that, is it safe to assume that the Response ( not response.body) object in the `onResponse` method will always be NonNull?

If it can be null, what can be the possible scenarios?

I looked online and on Retrofit docs, but no clear answers.

Comment: It can be null if the request had error.Look at the following answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527551/converting-json-response-to-pojo-with-retrofit-using-jsend-format/42625457#42625457

Comment: @ArpanSharma The `body()` or `errorBody()` can be null. The question asked about `Response` parameter

Comment: ok.No it can't be,answer is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be null.

You can see [in Retrofit source code](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/OkHttpCall.java#L186) that you only get a `Response.success` or a `Reponse.error` returned.

You can check if the HTTP request was a success using `Response.isSuccessful()`.

If the `Response` was possible to be null, then that method would throw a `NullPointerException`.

If there was a scenario for a null Response, or some exception thrown when parsing the response, then [`onFailure` would be entered](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/OkHttpCall.java#L107).